# Getting ftp_put progress

Tags: php, ftp

I have a PHP script on a web server that uploads a file to another remote server via `ftp_put`.

How can I display the current upload progress to the user?

The only similar system I've seen is for file uploads from the user, with ajax requests to check the local size of the uploaded file on the server.

The equivalent system would be ajax requests to the web server, that then checked file sizes on the remote server and returned that data to the user's clientscript.

This seems horribly inefficient to me. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

It can be implemented easily using [FTP URL protocol wrappers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php):

```
$url = "ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com/remote/dest/path/file.zip";
$local_path = "/local/source/path/file.zip";

$size = filesize($local_path) or die("Cannot retrieve size file");

$hout = fopen($url, "wb") or die("Cannot open destination file");
$hin = fopen($local_path, "rb") or die("Cannot open source file");

while (!feof($hin))
{
    $buf = fread($hin, 10240);
    fwrite($hout, $buf);
    echo "\r".intval(ftell($hin)/$size*100)."%";
}

echo "\n";

fclose($hin);
fclose($hout);
```

Comment: It worked also with an sftp upload.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If ftp server on other machine supports `REST` command (restart uploading from certain point) there is dirty way to implement this:

1. create temp file
2. put X bytes to this file from the file you want to upload
3. upload temp file
4. write status to another file (or session, but not sure if it will work)
5. append another X bytes to temp file
6. Upload temp file starting form X bytes
7. crite status to file
8. repeat 5-7 until whole file is uploaded
9. delete temp & status files.

Sample code:

```
$fs = filesize('file.bin');
define('FTP_CHUNK_SIZE', intval($fs * 0.1) ); // upload ~10% per iteration

$ftp = ftp_connect('localhost') or die('Unable to connect to FTP server');
ftp_login($ftp, 'login', 'pass') or die('FTP login failed');

$localfile = fopen('file.bin','rb');

$i = 0;
while( $i < $fs )
{
    $tmpfile = fopen('tmp_ftp_upload.bin','ab');
    fwrite($tmpfile, fread($localfile, FTP_CHUNK_SIZE));
    fclose($tmpfile);

    ftp_put($ftp, 'remote_file.bin', 'tmp_ftp_upload.bin', FTP_BINARY, $i);
    // Remember to put $i as last argument above

    $progress = (100 * round( ($i += FTP_CHUNK_SIZE)  / $fs, 2 ));
    file_put_contents('ftp_progress.txt', "Progress: {$progress}%");
}
fclose($localfile);
unlink('ftp_progress.txt');
unlink('tmp_ftp_upload.bin'); // delete when done
```

And file to check with ajax:

```
if(file_exists('ftp_progress.txt'))
    echo file_get_contents('ftp_progress.txt');
else
    echo 'Progress: 0%';
exit;
```

Comment: or you can just flush() the progress