# progress bar tracking with PHP and JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form which allow to upload a file in AJAX. It works well, and my progress bar as well. I have 2 questions about my code :

1st : how can i make it compatible with IE 10-

2nd : There is a way to keep the progress when i'm leaving the page ? At time, my progress bar is completing well, but if i leave and return to the page, the progress bar is empty. I would like to keep the progress (eg: my progress bar shows 30%, i leave and return the page after a while, it now shows 55%) ?

My code :

```
$('#submitfile').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($('#form-import-file')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ path('el_go_to_upload_files') }}',
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function() {
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if(myXhr.upload){
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false); // For handling the progress of the upload
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        beforeSend: beforeSendHandler,
        success: completeHandler,
        error: errorHandler,
        // Form data
        data: formData,
        //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    }
});

// My progress handler
function progressHandlingFunction(e){
    if(e.lengthComputable){                                 
        $('progress').attr({value:e.loaded,max:e.total});
    }
}
```

Comment: For your first question please check this link :- http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2012/01/03/cross-browser-html5-progress-bars-in-depth/

Comment: Regarding to second question you need to check how much download happen and then show it in percentage dynamically.

Comment: Any idea how to do for the second question ?

Comment: Chek out the link :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216028/php-display-the-percent-of-ftp-get

Comment: Two function are there which  you can use to get file size of your downloaded file.and then do some mathematics to fin out percentage download.