# Does using FTP URL Protocol Wrapper equals using FTP for copying file?

Tags: php, ftp

I'm trying to create FTP Process that output its progress.

I found this answer rather simple on [Getting ftp_put progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885468/getting-ftp-put-progress)
by Martin Prikryl

```
<?php
$local_path = "\Local\Path\Local_File.zip";
$remote_path = 'ftp://username:password@address/Remote_File.zip';

$size = filesize($local_path);

$hin = fopen($local_path, "rb") or die("Cannot open source file");
$hout = fopen($remote_path, "wb") or die("Cannot open destination file");

while (!feof($hin))
{
    $buf = fread($hin, 10240);
    fwrite($hout, $buf);
    echo "\r".intval(ftell($hin)/$size*100)."%";
}

fclose($hin);
fclose($hout);
```

This code is working.

What I want to ask is, if I were to use FTP URL Protocol Wrapper (ftp://) as the URL. Does it copy file using the FTP? Or is it just copying with a normal PHP Command?

Because I was asked to create an FTP process for my project, but I need the progress when it is copying.

Thanks before :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FTP URL wrapper uses FTP protocol under the hood. That's why they are called "FTP".

I have no idea, what you mean by *"copying with a normal PHP Command"*. If your only interface to the server is FTP, and the wrapper were using anything else than FTP, then the wrapper would obviously fail. If it works, it only proves that it uses FTP.

Documentation for [FTP URL protocol wrapper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php) says:

> Allows read access to existing files and creation of new files **via FTP**. If the server does not support passive mode ftp, the connection will fail.

Comment: Hi Sir..! I took your code about this one haha. I mean, like using a normal copy method provided by php (which I believe didn't use FTP Protocol). I just want to make sure that this copy file with buffer process is FTP process. Because normal method will took longer and has a rather small file size restriction than FTP. I'm new to FTP and has tried to understand about it for a while. Thanks for the clarification. :)